# How do I separate test types with the template extern keywords?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some type `X` which is templated on `T`:

```
// hpp file
template <typename T>
struct X
{
  int Get();
};

extern template X<TraitsType>;

// cpp file
template <typename T>
int X<T>::Get() { return T::Get(); }

template X<TraitsType>;
```

The type `T` might be a random number generator in a production environment (`TraitsType`), but for the sake of unit tests it might be a type that will generate predictable or fudgible values (say, `TestTraitsType`). If I want to use this `TestTraitsType` I now have to scatter `extern template` and `template` declarations for `X<TestTraitsType>` throughout my `hpp` and `cpp` files, which is undesirable because I am polluting my production code with unit test code.

How can I avoid this while keeping these type instantiations in separate translation units?

Comment: You can't really have your cake and eat it too -- either put the implementation in the header file or explicitly instantiate every specialization you will ever need.

Answer (score 1):

Move method definitions in (private) header *.inl* (or *.hxx*)

- ```
  // inl file
  template <typename T>
  int X<T>::Get() { return T::Get(); }
  ```
- ```
  // cpp file
  #include "X.inl"

  template X<TraitsType>;
  ```
- ```
  // test file
  #include "X.inl"

  template X<TestTraitsType>;
  ```